# Check if element exist in list, if it doesn't append to the list

Tags: tcl

I want to have a list of items, namely coordinates of a point (x,y,z). Now, keeping value of x same i want to increase the values of y and z and do something inside the for loops.

```
set x [string range $x1 1 $lgthx];
set lst_nodes [list $x 0 0];
for { set y 0}  {$y < 1000} {incr y} {
    for { set z 0}  {$z < 1000} {incr z} {
        # Here i want to check if the item is present in the list or not
        set lst_nodes [lappend $lst_nodes [<Do something here> $x $y $z]];
    }
}
```

I tried many options to make this work. But, i am getting errors like for the value of x: **invalid command name "215.5623"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lappend`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm) works on variable name, not the variable itself, so `[lappend lst_nodes [<Do something here> $x $y $z]];`.

Also, `lappend` modifies the list. I'm not sure why you are using `set`.

Assuming that with the above changes the script works, then to do the check, I would use something like this ([`ni`](https://wiki.tcl.tk/17963) means 'not in' and returns true if an element is not present in a list):

```
set x [string range $x1 1 $lgthx]
set lst_nodes [list [list $x 0 0]]
for {set y 0}  {$y < 1000} {incr y} {
    for {set z 0}  {$z < 1000} {incr z} {
        # Here i want to check if the item is present in the list or not
        set new_node [<Do something here> $x $y $z]
        if {$new_node ni $lst_nodes} {
            lappend lst_nodes $new_node
        }
    }
}
```

I wrapped `[list $x 0 0]` into another list because I believe you are keeping a list of lists (these being the coordinates). If you are not, then you need to append each element to the list instead of appending a list (the new node) using [list expansion](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158) `lappend lst_nodes {*}$new_node`.

Comment: I followed the same code written by you, it still throws the same error. consider x has 123.566 value.

Comment: @Damien Then it will be the command you are using. `<Do something here>`. Without knowing how it works, I cannot help there :( If I use `list` instead of `<Do something here>`, I have no issues.

Comment: Okay, let's remove <Do something here> and let it be only those 3 values like `set new_node [$x $y $z]`. I tried this as well and i get the same error

Comment: @Damien No, you cannot just use it like that. It should be `set new_node [list $x $y $z]` When you do `[$x $y $z]`, it means execute the procedure `$x` (after substitution) with parameters `$y` and `$z`.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks for your quick help.